# Using powershell to edit the "Date taken" property to match its "Date modified" for multiple files

Tags: powershell, properties

I was taking pictures of an event, and when I came home to check them, I noticed that the camera's clock is set to an hour forward, which is then carried on to all pictures taken. I was able to find some code that allows me to modify the "Date modified", though I would like to know if there is a way to change the "Date taken" property to match the "Date modified".

This is the code I used in adjusting the "Date modified" to the correct times:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'directory' -File -Recurse) | ForEach-Object{$_.LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime.addHours(-1)}
```

I did some digging and found something involving GetPropertyItem(36867) and another involving $propIndex, but I don't know how to integrate it into my code to solve the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could use the [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) by Phil Harvey to get the desired information. ;-)

Comment: does ExifTool work on .jpg's and .mp4's?

Comment: Click on the link!!  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Great to hear. You may share your solution with the world to help others with the same or a similar issue.  ;-)

Comment: it doesn't seem top work on .mp4 files. any help with that?

Comment: Please show your code. What exactly does that mean  "*it doesn't seem top work*"? What happens? Or what does not happen but you expect it to happen?  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`